# Ошибка в Android-приложении

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment

Делаю приложение под Android. В нем хочу реализовать много функций, чтобы набраться опыта. Одной из таких функций является чтение файлов в формате pdf. Будет реализованна библиотека, состоящая из "плашек", при нажатии на которые будет открываться сопутствующий pdf файл. Застрял в самом начале: проблема с отображением этих самых "плашек". Код перед вами:

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.testapp

import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

lateinit var booksLayout: LinearLayout

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        booksLayout = findViewById(R.id.books)
        val bookSection = BookSection()
        bookSection.createBookSection()

    }
}
```

BookSection.kt

```
package com.example.testapp

import android.content.res.Configuration
import android.widget.FrameLayout
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import kotlin.math.ceil

class BookSection {

    fun createBookSection(){

        val ma = MainActivity()

        val booksAmount = 7

        val bookWidth = ma.resources.getDimension(R.dimen.book_width).toInt()
        val bookHeight = ma.resources.getDimension(R.dimen.book_height).toInt()
        val bookMargin = ma.resources.getDimension(R.dimen.book_margin).toInt()
        val backgroundParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(bookWidth, bookHeight)
        val pictureParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        )
        val authorParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        )

        val bookBackground = Array(booksAmount, {createBookBackground()})
        val bookPicture = Array(booksAmount, {createBookPicture()})

        backgroundParams.setMargins(bookMargin, 0, 0, 0)
        authorParams.setMargins(0, bookMargin, 0, 0)

        for (i in bookBackground.indices) {
            bookBackground[i].layoutParams = backgroundParams
            bookPicture[i].layoutParams = pictureParams

            bookBackground[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.books_background_active)
            bookPicture[i].setBackgroundResource(getImage(i + 1))

            bookBackground[i].addView(bookPicture[i])

            bookBackground[i].setOnClickListener {
                if (bookBackground[i].getChildAt(0) == bookPicture[i]) {
                    bookBackground[i].removeView(bookPicture[i])
                } else {
                    bookBackground[i].addView(bookPicture[i])
                }
            }
        }

        if (ma.resources.configuration.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){

            val bookRowsAmountVertical: Int = (ceil(booksAmount / 3f)).toInt()
            val bookRowsVertical = Array( bookRowsAmountVertical, {createBookInfo()})

            for (i in bookRowsVertical.indices){
                bookRowsVertical[i].layoutParams = authorParams
                bookRowsVertical[i].orientation = LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL
                for (j in 0 until 3){
                    if (i * 3 + j == booksAmount) { break }
                    bookRowsVertical[i].addView(bookBackground[i * 3 + j])
                }
                ma.booksLayout.addView(bookRowsVertical[i])
            }

        } else {

            val bookRowsAmountHorizontal: Int = (ceil(booksAmount / 6f)).toInt()
            val bookRowsHorizontal = Array( bookRowsAmountHorizontal, {createBookInfo()})

            for (i in bookRowsHorizontal.indices){
                bookRowsHorizontal[i].layoutParams = authorParams
                bookRowsHorizontal[i].orientation = LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL
                for (j in 0 until 6){
                    if (i * 6 + j == booksAmount) { break }
                    bookRowsHorizontal[i].addView(bookBackground[(i * 6) + j])
                }
                ma.booksLayout.addView(bookRowsHorizontal[i])
            }

        }

    }

    private fun createBookInfo(): LinearLayout {
        val ma = MainActivity()
        return LinearLayout(ma)
    }

    private fun getImage(i:Int): Int {
        val ma = MainActivity()
        return ma.resources.getIdentifier("book_$i", "drawable", ma.packageName)
    }

    private fun createBookBackground (): FrameLayout {
        val ma = MainActivity()
        return FrameLayout(ma)
    }

    private fun createBookPicture (): ImageView {
        val ma = MainActivity()
        return ImageView(ma)
    }
}
```

Изначально весь код был в классе **MainActivity.kt**, но потом я решил почистить его: вывести код, отвечающий за отображение библиотеки в отдельный класс. Получилось то, что получилось.

Ошибка

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.context.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы создаете `MainActivity()` в нескольких местах в классе `BookSection`, но класс `Activity` предназначен только для создания системой Android. При создании система Android предоставляет контекст приложения (`Application Context`) для `Activity`. Создавая же `Activity` самостоятельно, у него не будет контекста, что и вызывает ошибку при попытке получить его. К тому же создание `MainActivity` самостоятельно не имеет никакого смысла, ведь вам нужно обратиться к существующему экземпляру `MainActivity`, а не создавать новый. Чтобы исправить ваш класс, вы можете передавать ему в конструктор `MainActivity` вот так:

```
class BookSection(private val mainActivity: MainActivity) {
...
}
```

и далее заменить везде в классе `MainActivity()` на `mainActivity`. Потом использовать класс так:

```
val bookSection = BookSection(this)
bookSection.createBookSection()
```

Однако для отображения списков в Android приложениях следует использовать [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview).